# Want to use Ubuntu on 32bit server

Tags: server

I have a 32bit window server running 2003 that I need to update to linux.  I run a website on it.  Will the newest server version run on a 32 bit machine?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just choose the i386 architecture at the download, not the amd64 (which is not only for amd but also for intels 64 bit x86 chips).

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads

Ubuntu 14.04.2 Server 32 Bit